# login failed, although I specified the inbound rule in my security group of RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch

At first try I made an instance of DB and also my local DB was immigrated to the AWS instance DB and then tried to deploy the WAR in my environment on AWS but it couldn't connect to the DB instance, although the instance of DB on AWS  was working well with my local tomcat container, I also read the documents of how to connect from environment to the existing DB, but it didn't help either. 
In the recent try, I made a new environment and made an DB instance concurrently; although I defined inbound rule (All traffic,all protocol, all port ranges), the new instance on MySQL can't make connection to DB instance on AWS. Would you please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you deploy an RDS instance which is publicly accessible or not [1]? If the RDS instance is private, where is your EC2 instance (same region, same VPC?). Are you sure that database endpoint, user, and password in your application are correct?

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html